# How to compile big c++ project using MsBuild.exe with x64 compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I have the big Visual Studio 2015 C++ project and can't compile it on the computer with 12GB RAM (fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space).

Command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" Project.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64
```

I've read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4d2c09s.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
and decided to use x64 compiler, but I can't figure out how it can be done using MsBuild.exe (or with another way but without generate make file - it is hard to maintain it because the project frequently changed).

I was tried to call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat" before MsBuild.exe, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662426.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Where is the property PreferredToolArchitecture which by default equals x86. 
Set it to x64 to use the 64-bit compiler and tools to build your application.

```
msbuild myProject.vcxproj /p:PreferredToolArchitecture=x64
```